# How can I make a brick-built wheelbarrow?

Tags: building, city

I'd like to make a brick-built wheelbarrow to fit on a construction site that can be held by minifigures hands. I've seen prefabricated Duplo/Fabuland wheelbarrows as well as a new wheelbarrow in a [2012 CITY set](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4206-2) which doesn't really appeal to me.

I don't mind using SNOT techniques and Technic elements. I've already tried making one out of Technic [L shaped lift arms](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=32526).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Brickshelf](http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/search.cgi?q=wheelbarrow&stype=dfic) returns two interesting designs:

[image: Wheelbarrow by]

[image: Wheelbarrow by]

There's also a [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0HEm8_mDf8) showing yet another design which is quite simple yet elegant (although I would have put the 1x2 plate with handles under it, not on the side, but that's my own opinion.